# pyspider phantom is not enabled ;501 Sever Error

Tags: phantomjs, pyspider

I used pyspider to crawl a website, when using PhantomJs, an error occurred as follows:

[image]

[image]

I've searched for the solutions in https://github.com/binux/pyspider/issues/215, 
the author's seemed to solute it, so I tried, but it didn't still. How to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if phantomjs is in $PATH
try the following:

```
phantomjs -v
```

or try the following and check the output

```
pyspider phantomjs
```

it should output

```
phantomjs fetcher running on port 25555
```

Otherwise you will need to install phantomjs on your system.